# FFmpeg - Buffer queue overflow, dropping - when combining 2 videos and using concat, hstack and trim

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to merge two videos using concat and hstack but getting buffer overflow error resulting in the one of the video getting paused for few seconds.

I tried adding fifo and h264 video codec as suggested on this forum but the issue persists.

Can someone please let me know the issue in this command? Many thanks in advance.

```
ffmpeg -i 1_a.opus -i 2_a.opus -i 1_v.mp4 -i 2_v_bars.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=15720|15720[a1]; [0:a][a1]amix; [3:v]trim=0:15.81,geq=0:128:128,fifo [silence]; [silence][3:v]concat,fifo [3_v_silence]; [3_v_silence][2:v]hstack,fifo" -vcodec libx264 -strict experimental -y out_fifo_h264_2.mp4
```

Following is the output:

```
ffmpeg version 4.0.2-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Input #0, ogg, from '1_a.opus':
  Duration: 00:01:03.82, start: -0.020000, bitrate: 37 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
Input #1, ogg, from '2_a.opus':
  Duration: 00:00:52.40, start: -0.020000, bitrate: 44 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1_v.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:01:03.83, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2313 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 2302 kb/s, 333 fps, 333 tbr, 10656 tbn, 666 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2_v_bars.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:00:52.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 286 kb/s
    Stream #3:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 284 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (opus) -> amix:input0
  Stream #1:0 (opus) -> adelay
  Stream #2:0 (h264) -> hstack:input1
  Stream #3:0 (h264) -> trim
  Stream #3:0 (h264) -> concat:in1:v0
  amix -> Stream #0:0 (aac)
  fifo -> Stream #0:1 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x50722c0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x50722c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 Cache64 SlowShuffle
[libx264 @ 0x50722c0] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x50722c0] 264 - core 155 r2901 7d0ff22 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'out_fifo_h264_2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 aac
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 8:3], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Past duration 0.924919 too large
[Parsed_concat_5 @ 0x52e2e00] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.trate= 415.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=3349 speed=0.955x    
    Last message repeated 11 times
[Parsed_concat_5 @ 0x52e2e00] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.trate= 394.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=3533 speed=0.962x    
    Last message repeated 11 times
[Parsed_concat_5 @ 0x52e2e00] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.trate= 376.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=3698 speed=0.963x    
    Last message repeated 11 times
[Parsed_concat_5 @ 0x52e2e00] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.trate= 362.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=3851 speed=0.96x    
    Last message repeated 12 times
[Parsed_concat_5 @ 0x52e2e00] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.trate= 345.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=4033 speed=0.965x    
    Last message repeated 13 times
[Parsed_concat_5 @ 0x52e2e00] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.trate= 331.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=4208 speed=0.969x    
    Last message repeated 12 times
[Parsed_concat_5 @ 0x52e2e00] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.trate= 318.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=4381 speed=0.971x    
    Last message repeated 12 times
[Parsed_concat_5 @ 0x52e2e00] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.trate= 305.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=4555 speed=0.974x    
    Last message repeated 12 times
[Parsed_concat_5 @ 0x52e2e00] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.trate= 294.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=4733 speed=0.977x    
    Last message repeated 13 times
[Parsed_concat_5 @ 0x52e2e00] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.trate= 283.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=4912 speed=0.98x    
    Last message repeated 12 times
[Parsed_concat_5 @ 0x52e2e00] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.trate= 410.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=5094 speed=0.984x    
    Last message repeated 10 times
frame= 1706 fps= 26 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4924kB time=00:01:08.16 bitrate= 591.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=21053 speed=1.02x    
video:3914kB audio:958kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.061062%
[aac @ 0x5040040] Qavg: 22388.959
[libx264 @ 0x50722c0] frame I:7     Avg QP:15.90  size: 26657
[libx264 @ 0x50722c0] frame P:502   Avg QP:19.36  size:  5413
[libx264 @ 0x50722c0] frame B:1197  Avg QP:23.11  size:   922
[libx264 @ 0x50722c0] consecutive B-frames:  5.2%  1.9%  5.5% 87.5%
[libx264 @ 0x50722c0] mb I  I16..4: 26.8% 56.4% 16.7%
[libx264 @ 0x50722c0] mb P  I16..4:  3.0%  2.8%  0.6%  P16..4: 21.6%  6.4%  3.2%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:62.3%
[libx264 @ 0x50722c0] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8: 18.8%  0.9%  0.1%  direct: 0.4%  skip:79.5%  L0:49.1% L1:48.8% BI: 2.1%
[libx264 @ 0x50722c0] 8x8 transform intra:45.7% inter:70.7%
[libx264 @ 0x50722c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 39.5% 57.5% 22.6% inter: 4.2% 6.4% 0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x50722c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 22% 31% 19% 28%
[libx264 @ 0x50722c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 26% 23% 38%  2%  2%  2%  2%  3%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x50722c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 35% 29% 21%  2%  3%  4%  2%  3%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x50722c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 55% 23% 18%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x50722c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x50722c0] ref P L0: 65.6% 12.4% 16.1%  5.9%
[libx264 @ 0x50722c0] ref B L0: 85.0% 12.2%  2.7%
[libx264 @ 0x50722c0] ref B L1: 95.4%  4.6%
[libx264 @ 0x50722c0] kb/s:469.82
```

Answer (score 0):

The FIFOs should be inserted for inputs whose use will be delayed.

So, the command should be

```
ffmpeg -i 1_a.opus -i 2_a.opus -i 1_v.mp4 -i 2_v_bars.mp4 -filter_complex \
       "[1:a]adelay=15720|15720[a1]; [0:a][a1]amix;\
        [3:v]trim=0:15.81,geq=0:128:128[silence];[3:v]fifo[3v];[silence][3v]concat[3_v_silence];\
        [3_v_silence][2:v]hstack" -vcodec libx264 -y out_fifo_h264_2.mp4
```

You're using v4.0.2 so `-strict` is not needed.